Change installation of pytorch from CUDA-based torch to CPU-based torch in docker-build
I have a poetry-based project I'd like to pack into a docker image. For that, I use the following docker script:
FROM python:3.12 AS builder

ARG CUR_GIT_COMMIT
ENV CUR_GIT_COMMIT=$CUR_GIT_COMMIT

RUN pip install poetry==1.8.4
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 libegl-dev -y

ENV POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=1 \
    POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/tmp/poetry_cache

WORKDIR /test_project

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
RUN touch README.md

# RUN poetry install --without dev --no-root
# RUN poetry install --no-root
RUN poetry install --without dev --no-root && rm -rf ${POETRY_CACHE_DIR}

FROM python:3.12-slim AS runtime 

ARG CUR_GIT_COMMIT
ENV CUR_GIT_COMMIT=$CUR_GIT_COMMIT

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/test_project/.venv \
    PATH="/test_project/.venv/bin:${PATH}"

WORKDIR /test_project

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 libegl-dev -y

COPY --from=builder ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ${VIRTUAL_ENV}

COPY test_project ./test_project
COPY run_test_project.py ./


ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "run_test_project"]

However, as my project contains pytorch with CUDA, the resulting image has a size of > 8 GByte, much larger than what is supported by my repository. Therefore, I want to switch out my CUDA-based torch with a CPU-based torch build, but only in the docker-image. As my current implementation of torch in pyproject.toml is defined as
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.10,<3.13"
torch = { version = "^2.5.1+cu124", source = "pytorch" }
torchaudio = { version = "^2.1.1", source = "pytorch" }
torchvision = { version = "^0.20.0+cu124", source = "pytorch" }

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "pytorch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124"
priority = "explicit"

the idea was to replace the package names and -url with the cpu-based url before creating the docker image, using
RUN sed -i -e "s%whl/cu124%whl/cpu%g" ./pyproject.toml
RUN sed -i -e "s%+cu124%%g" ./pyproject.toml
RUN poetry lock --no-update

However, this still installs all nvidia-related packages, blowing up the image unnecessarily.

You don't need to sed. Poetry can select different sources for the package based on the environment. I'm not sure how you'll be able to detect you are in docker though. See: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/6409#issuecomment-1798247485
